# How to place labels on top of the margin?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot with epslatex terminal. I want to know how to  put the 
label on top of a margin, so that the part of margin under the label is invisible. In the figure I attached, the part of margin under the label 
is still visible.

[image: the unsatisfied plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you should be able to tell gnuplot to put your text labels into a box by using the `set label ... front boxed`, and the specify that the box should be opaque and white using something like `set style textbox opaque noborder fillcolor rgb "white"`. However, this is not supported by all terminals, and `epslatex` seems to be one of those where this doesn't work.

However, in `epslatex` you can simply use latex commands to create a white background box around your label text:

```
set term epslatex standalone
set outp "test.tex"
set label "\\colorbox{white}{This is a label}" at 6.,0.5 front
plot sin(x)
set output
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I solved it by put a box first and then add text, but your solution is far more elegant.